# Docker File with python 3.8 and specific modules for Jetson Nano Dev Kit

Tags: python, docker, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have an application for artificial vision. It needs: python 3.8, numpy 1.18.4, cv2 4.2.0.34, keyboard 0.13.5 and YoloV4.

How can i create a docker file to run a container with all this specific modules?

I tried to install containers with any modules but i dont know how to install the others modules in the same container.